How to decide which protein structure to use from multiple entries in the Protein Data Bank?
I am trying to analyze the structure of SARS-CoV-2 spike protein. There are thousands of entries when searching for it on RCSB website. I have narrowed it down to 2 best matches (6VXX and 6XR8). For 6VXX, it is one of the first structure to be reported on RCSB website. The structure is heavily cited (>10000) but possess 5 point mutations, and sequence coverage is 14-1211. On the other hand, 6XR8 is cited less (>1000) in comparison with no mutations and sequence coverage 1-1273. I want the original strain with closed pre-fusion conformation. How to decide which structure to use for downstream application?

What downstream application did you have in mind? which structure to use is going to depend on that.

@timeskull I want to mutate some regions of the protein to see how it changes the binding dynamics with ACE2 protein and antibodies.

Mutations compared to what? The CoV spike is highly mutable as this is part of the immune evasion strategy. You should use one that suits your purpose. The first published usually has the most references simply because of time, it doesn't mean it is the "best" one to use, much like first answers on here tend to be more upvoted than later because they have had more time for exposure, even if the answer is incorrect.

@bob1 Mutations compared to the canonical sequence (UniProt ID: P0DTC2). Yes, there are multiple structures for the same protein (same amino acid sequence) with no standardization on RCSB.
